# Literal field Google Sheets QUERY

Tags: sql, google-sheets, string-literals

Is there a way to add a literal field at the end of a Google Sheets QUERY function similar to what you can do in SQL?

e.g. `=QUERY(A:C,"SELECT A, B, C, D AS 'CURRENT DATA'",0)`

Thanks,
Stefan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Guess, you mean this:

`=QUERY(A:C,"SELECT A, B, C, 'D' label 'D' 'CURRENT DATA'",0)`

see [more info here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

The formula above will populate letter 'D', lebaled as 'CURRENT DATA'.
If you want actual column D, then use range `A:D`:

`=QUERY(A:D,"SELECT A, B, C, D label 'D' 'CURRENT DATA'",0)`

---

**More columns**

Also possible to add more columns in any order. This formula would work:

`=QUERY(A1:C4,"SELECT A, C, 'D', B, date '2016-05-30', 500 label 'D' 'CURRENT DATA', date '2016-05-30' 'MY DATE', 500 'MY NUMBER'",0)`

here we select:

- Column `A`
- Column `C`
- *custom text*
- Column B
- *custom date*
- *custom number*

Answer (score 1):

All I had to do was:

```
=QUERY(A:C,"SELECT A, B, C, 'D'",0)
```

This will give a literal `D` for all rows of your query.