# Add a column with a specific value when making google sheet "=QUERY"

Tags: google-sheets

I am sorting an array made up of 2 queries.
I want to add an additional row per query with a prefilled value.

Full query:

```
=SORT({
    QUERY(Materials!A4:K,"SELECT A,D,K,J where B='"&Home!C9&"'") ;
    QUERY(Labour!A4:K,"SELECT A,D,H,G where B='"&Home!C9&"'") 
}, 1, 1)
```

Example of currently returned columns/values:

```
QUERY(Materials!A4:K,"SELECT A,D,K,J where B='"&Home!C9&"'")

date1, supplier1, notes1, amount1
date2, supplier1, notes2, amount2
date3, supplier2, notes3, amount4

QUERY(Labour!A4:K,"SELECT A,D,H,G where B='"&Home!C9&"'") 
date1, joblocation1, notes1, amount1
date2, joblocation2, notes2, amount2
```

What I would like the final output to be:

```
Name1, Materials, supplier1, notes1, amount1
Name2, Materials, supplier1, notes2, amount2
Name3, Materials, supplier2, notes3, amount4

date1, Labour, notes1, amount1
date2, Labour, notes2, amount2
```

.. thus as per the title, "adding a column with a specific value when making a google sheet query"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Literal field Google Sheets QUERY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770585/literal-field-google-sheets-query)

Comment: From your given expected output it seems you want additional columns not row. Am I correct?

Comment: @A.Steer I found my answer derived from that answer yes thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To Add an additional untitled column, here is one possible solution:

```
QUERY(Materials!A4:K,"SELECT A,D,K,J where B='"&Home!C9&"'")
```

To

```
QUERY(Materials!A4:K,"SELECT A,'NewColValue',D,K,J where B='"&Home!C9&"' label 'NewColValue' ''")
```